# Stack Formbricks with traefik, 404 error, using docker and portainer

Tags: docker, stack, portainer

I have a docker swarm and portainer installation.

I've created a formbricks stack, the image comes up normally, the container is created and the database is also created.

Everything seems to work fine, but when I access it through my domain using traefik, I get a 404 error.

> Progress: resolved 6, reused 0, downloaded 6, added 6, done
> .../node_modules/@prisma/engines postinstall
> nodescripts/postinstall.js.../nodemodules/@prisma/enginespostinstall:Done.../prisma@5.9.1/node
> m odules/prismapreinstall node scripts/preinstall-entry.js
> .../prisma@5.9.1/node_modules/prisma preinstall: Done
> Environment variables loaded from .env
> Prisma schema loaded from packages/database/schema.prisma
> Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "formbricks", schema "public" at "pgbouncer:5432"
> 64 migrations found in prisma/migrations
> No pending migrations to apply.
> ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
> Local: http://localhost:3000
> Network: http://0.0.0.0:3000 ✓ Ready in 130ms

And that's my stack:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:

  formbricks:
    image: formbricks/formbricks:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@postgres:5432/formbricks?schema=public
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBAPP_URL="https://test.com"
      - NEXTAUTH_SECRET=sbyxuu4x4sk4u8a4rrhmevbqvq2coe5wvuz2swwix
      - NEXTAUTH_URL="https://test.com"
      - ENCRYPTION_KEY=i42w835mttn4869ubyqx4x6nxee
      - EMAIL_VERIFICATION_DISABLED=1
      - PASSWORD_RESET_DISABLED=1
    volumes:
      - uploads:/apps/web/uploads/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - network_public
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
            # - node.hostname == worker1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 2048M
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.formbricks.rule=Host(`test.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.formbricks.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.services.formbricks.loadbalancer.server.port=80


volumes:
  uploads:
    external: true
    name: uploads

networks:
  network_public:
    name: network_public
    external: true
```

I've tried a few ways and I can't figure it out.

I've tried putting `WEBAPP_URL="https://test.com`, but it doesn't work.